# Angular: how to know if an application is loaded through an iframe?

Tags: angular, iframe

Is there a reliable way to detect that an angular application is loaded through an iframe? I would like to have two version of my angular app:
one when loaded from iframe and another from regular browsing.

I cannot assume the parent would send any message to my iframe. I can only assume a third party would integrate an iframe html tag I communicate to him.
Also, I have no control on the URL integrated to the iframe, reason being compatibility.

Comment: You can use `sendMessage` to communicate from parent to the iFrame (be aware, they need to be in the same domain). Whenever your application in the iFrame has loaded up you can send the message to the parent and then do some logic.

Comment: The parent would be in another domain and would be a third party, thus cannot assume I can execute any script from parent.

Comment: The logic will be quite the same. Instead of using sendMessage you could use an API instead.

Comment: Sorry I don't grasp it. What do you mean using an API?

Comment: Since the parent would be in another domain you can't communicate using WS or events, that's why an API would do the trick. You call an endpoint from the Angular's app and catch it as you please in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If possible try to use a route prefix for instances where you load your application as sub module

EX:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/app", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "app", component: AppComponent ,  data :{ isModule: false}},
  { path: "app-module", component: AppComponent,  data :{ isModule: true}}
];
```

Now for your normal use route will be

https://yourdomain.com/app/child-route

For iframes you can use

https://yourdomain.com/app-module/child-route

This will also give you the ability to add two auth guards for two use cases of your application.

in your app you can use

```
constructor(private activatedroute:ActivatedRoute) {
 }

 ngOnInit() {
      this.activatedroute.data.subscribe(data => {
           this.isModule = data.isModule;
       })
 }
```